# find $\gcd(2n+1,n)$ assuming that $n$ is non negative integer

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

Should I use the rule 
$$n=(2n+1)\cdot q+r$$
I am not sure how to find the gcd while $n$ is unknown 
or should I assume that the numbers will be odd so the gcd will be $1$?

Comment: I try to solve it this way suppose gcd(2n+1,n)=a, then we have
a|2n+1;a|n
. So there exists t1,t2 such that 2n+1=at1 and n=at2, so from this two equations we get
at1+1=at2⟺a(t2−t1)=1
. So, a=1

Comment: Notice that if $d$ is a common divisor of $n$, $2n+1$, then it is also common divisor of $2n, 2n+1$. Hence it is a common divisor of $1=(2n+1)-2n$. What can we conclude?

Comment: You made things difficult by trying to divide $n$ by $2n+1$.  It will be easier to apply the division algorithm (quotient and remainder) for $2n+1$ divided by $n$.

Comment: The remarkable thing is that you can Euclid's algorithm to find this gcd, even with $n$ being unknown!

Comment: @ Hurky can you explain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct (except for an arithmetic error - $2n+1=a t_1$ and $n = at_2$ means that $2at_1+1=a t_2$). But your conclusion holds.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Eucledean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm), where you actually would get the "last line" of the algorithm straight up which shows that the "last nonzero remainder" is $1$, so the $GCD$ is $1$. For $\gcd(2n+1,n)$

$$
2n+1=2\cdot n +1
$$
$$
n=1\cdot n +0. 
$$

---

EDIT after comment:

Try to read up on the wiki link I put in my answer, but I take two concrete examples here.

Say you would like to find $\gcd(30,7)$, according to the algorithm you would write:

$$
30=7\cdot4 +2
$$
$$
7=3\cdot 2 +1 
$$
$$
3=3\cdot 1+0
$$

In the last row the remaider is $0$ so the last nonzero remainder is $1$ therefore $\gcd(30,7)=1$

Say you would like to find $\gcd(40, 12)$ then you would write

$$
40=3\cdot 12 +4
$$
$$
12=3\cdot 4+0
$$

The last nonzero remainder is $4$ therefore $\gcd(40,12)=4$

Eventually you can look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2337896/calculate-mathrmgcd10n3-5n2) as well.

Comment: explain, please

Comment: @ghadah32 I edited the answer hope it helps to clear things up, if not just let me know